# How do you transfer MCPE worlds to PC?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a world that I would like to put on my PC for backup reasons. My tablet is a Kindle Fire and my PC runs Windows 10. How might I go about accomplishing this task?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Arqade! Just some advice (I may be wrong), but I am *pretty* sure MCPE and Java Edition are incompatable, since one is written in C++ and the other in Java.

Comment: They are two different games. You could just as well ask to convert Terraria maps into Roblox maps. Sure, there might be a tool out there that tries its best, but there aren't really compatible.

Comment: If what you want is just a file that you could restore to your Kindle, then it is OK to copy the save file to your computer. However, you cannot run the game using that world, as the Java edition is different and not compatible with the PE version. However, you can download an emulator app that supports games like Minecraft PE on your computer. One of them, Bluestacks, can be found [here](https://www.bluestacks.com/).

Comment: Are you using the Java or Windows 10 version of the game? If the former, then yes, it is not possible. If the latter, you can export the world and run the file on your computer to import it into the Win10 version.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to making a backup on your PC. You can simply upload the world from the "games" folder. I recommend ES File Explorer for this one as it shows the icon of the apps. Also, the "games" folder is located OUTSIDE the Android folder. The world name would be random. Just try to find the world that you want to upload by opening the world folder and looking at it's "world_icon.jpeg" file. Upload that world to Google Drive and download it from your computer. Simple as that!

Comment: NOTE: There are multiple folders in the "games" folder. Open the Minecraftworlds folder and follow the world icon step.